# Parse JSON string with C#

Tags: c#, json

I try to find a solution to parse a JSON string with C#.

Actually, I extract a JSON string from a file with:

```
string json = r.ReadToEnd();
```

In this JSON file I have a list of file associated with a status, like that:

```
{"C:\workspace\folder\test\added.txt": "synced","C:\workspace\folder\test\pending.test": "pending"}
```

I want to load this JSON and get each key/val pair.

But when I load the json with:

```
JObject jsonVal = JObject.Parse(json);
```

This line give me an error...

So, what is the method ? And how can I do to get each key without its name ? I thought about something like that:

```
string val = (string)jsonVal[0];
```

Edit: With Visual Studio, when I take a look at the json var, Visual Studio say me "String is not Json formatted"...

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: It gives you an error and you don't know why? We don't know why either! You should include the message in your question. We're not sitting at your computer watching you over your shoulder. Also, have you run your JSON string through [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/)? It says you don't have valid JSON. You can't parse JSON if it's not valid.

Comment: Your example of JSON is invalid. The backslashes must be escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  "C:\\workspace\\folder\\test\\added.txt": "synced",
  "C:\\workspace\\folder\\test\\pending.test": "pending"
}
```

Your JSON needs those backslashes escaped. Notice the \\

http://json.org/